# Setting CRS in Python 3 / tkinter

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, ogr

I've written some code to create a GUI which creates and then converts .CSV to .SHP. I'm mostly done however, I've made a mistake in the way I want to select CRS (using a drop down list), the code runs and doesn't output any errors, however the projection file isn't created and coordinate reference system doesn't get assigned.

```
def convert_csv_to_shp():
csv_path = path_entry3.get()
shp_path = path_entry4.get()

if csv_path and shp_path:
    input_crs_code = int(input_crs_var.get())
    output_crs_code = int(output_crs_var.get())

    # Create a new Shapefile datasource and layer
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    datasource = driver.CreateDataSource(shp_path)
    layer = datasource.CreateLayer('layer', geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint, srs=None)

    # Set the input and output coordinate systems
    input_crs = osr.SpatialReference()
    input_crs.ImportFromEPSG(int(input_crs_code))
    layer.spatialRef = input_crs  # Assign the spatial reference to the spatialRef property

    output_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    output_srs.ImportFromEPSG(int(output_crs_code))
    layer.spatialRef = input_crs  # Assign the spatial reference to the spatialRef property

    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(input_crs, output_srs)

     # Open the CSV file
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file)
        header = next(csv_data)
        for field_name in header:
            field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn(field_name, ogr.OFTString)
            layer.CreateField(field_defn)

        for csv_row in csv_data:
            feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
            x = float(csv_row[1])
            y = float(csv_row[2])
            point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
            point.AddPoint(x, y)
            point.Transform(transform)
            feature.SetGeometry(point)

            for i, value in enumerate(csv_row):
                feature.SetField(i, value)

            layer.CreateFeature(feature)
            feature = None

    # Close the datasource
    datasource = None

    # Display pop-up message
    messagebox.showinfo("Conversion Complete", "Conversion completed.")

else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please select input CSV and output Shapefile paths.")
```

Dropdown list for selecting input CRS.

```
frame5 = tk.LabelFrame(root, width=400, height=75, text="STEP 5: SELECT INPUT COORDINATE REFERENCE SYSTEM (CRS)", padx=5, pady=5)
frame5.propagate(False)
frame5.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")
frame5.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=40)
frame5.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=354)

input_crs_var = tk.StringVar(frame5)
input_crs_var.set("SELECT CRS")  # Default value

input_crs_label = tk.Label(frame5, text="INPUT COORDINATE REFERENCE SYSTEM - EPSG:")
input_crs_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

input_crs_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(frame5, textvariable=input_crs_var, values=["0", "27700", "3395", "2157"], width=20, state='readonly', justify='left')
input_crs_dropdown.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
```

Dropdown list for selecting output CRS

```
frame6 = tk.LabelFrame(root, width=500, height=75, text="STEP 6: SELECT OUTPUT COORDINATE REFERENCE SYSTEM (CRS)", padx=5, pady=5)
frame6.propagate(False)
frame6.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")
frame6.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=40)
frame6.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=358)

output_crs_var = tk.StringVar(frame6)
output_crs_var.set("SELECT CRS")  # Default value

output_crs_label = tk.Label(frame6, text="OUTPUT COORDINATE REFERENCE SYSTEM - EPSG:")
output_crs_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

output_crs_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(frame6, textvariable=output_crs_var, values=["0", "27700", "3395", "2157"], width=20, state='readonly', justify='left')
output_crs_dropdown.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
```

I'm very new to coding so can't get my head around this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example